# Google Sheets ImportXml() to extract data from table

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets

I am trying to retrieve a single cell data from an URL using IMPORTXML function but don't know how to expand the query. The below query retrieves all the rows.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bullion-rates.com/gold.htm", "//td[@class='rate']")

    1,276.84    ChartsHistory
    1,146.68    ChartsHistory
    1,011.26    ChartsHistory
    82,979      ChartsHistory
```

But I need only the data in the 4th row and 1st column (82,979). How to query it using importxml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered before. Try:

```
=index(IMPORTXML("https://www.bullion-rates.com/gold.htm", "//td[@class='rate']"),4,1)
```